# lazy load angular 2 components cache issue

Tags: angular, caching, lazy-loading

angular 2 naming lazy loaded components as 0.js 1.js ect. entry point have version prepended but all lazy loaded components remains same as before which results in inconsistent version of code in browser (main.js is new and 0.js browser uses old file)

Comment: Disable cache in chrome dev tools

Comment: so you suggest to do it for all users of the site? seriously?!

Comment: No just for development of course... When you generate a production build each bundle gets an unique name.

Comment: @RobinDijkhof Not true. Only if you change the code, then the hashing results into a different file name.

Comment: @dexter ofcourse. If you don't change the code there is no need to change the hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack offers chunk filename hash out of the box.
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-chunkfilename

simply added to my config file

```
chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js'
```

and the issue was solved!