# How to prevent Browser cache for a specific module in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

When we load a lazy load module by angular routing and inspect the network tab, we will see :

**(Status Code =200 OK)**

[image]

The second time, when we load the same module again and inspect the network tab we will see :

**(Status Code =304 Not Modified)**

[image]

As we can see, the second time, angular loads that module from cache , How to prevent cache here?

Comment: What's the reason you are trying to do that? If the bundle hasn't changed, there is no reason for the browser to re-download it, and for a good reason (performance).

Comment: It's your right ; it is good for performance, but Is there any way to re-download it?

Comment: You can, if you make the URL of the bundle unique each time. But once you make the URL of the bundle unique, you also need to change the references to it in the index.html file. For that, you need to republish your app.

Comment: @ ulmas - thanks, is there any complete guide to make the URL of the bundle unique ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [lazy load angular 2 components cache issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45629380/lazy-load-angular-2-components-cache-issue)

Comment: @Heretic Monkey - thanks -  where I have to add the config : ``chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js'`` , according to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45629380/lazy-load-angular-2-components-cache-issue

Answer (score 0):

To generate unique bundle names during the build time, you can:

1. Use the `--outputHashing` [option](https://angular.io/cli/build): `ng build --prod --outputHashing=all`
2. Update the configuration in `angular.json` under this path: `projects > [ project_name ] > architect > build > configurations > [ configuration_name ] > outputHashing` - set to `all`

This way, the hashed names get updated on each build. It won't generate unique hashes each time the user refreshes the browser.